# STaX parser behaving differently

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I am using java 6 and rt.jar has all the classes required to do STaX based parsing. Mainly I am using following classes:

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
```

When I run following as an java application:

```
while(reader.hasNext()) {            
XMLEvent elementsEvent = reader.nextEvent();
System.out.println(elementsEvent.toString());
--------
}
```

It works as expected, but when I deploy this into JBoss it behaves differently. Does anyone knows what might be the problem here?

Comment: Were you planning on telling us more than "it behaves differently"?

Comment: In case of SUN`s implementation the code above prints the text from xml file and in case of JBoss this prints the EventType

Comment: That's because `toString()` is intended as a human-readable representation. You shouldn't use that for "real" stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss uses the RI from here: http://stax.codehaus.org/Home for the STAX provider.  I would guess JDK probably uses SJSXP by default.

Since the behavior of `toString()` isn't specified on the API for `XMLEvent`, it's up to the implementation what it happens to feel like printing out.  Some implementations dump plain old `Object#toString()`, some might write out the XML, etc.  Effectively you're relying on implementation details that aren't specified by the javax package interfaces.

You can get consistent behavior by using the codehaus stax implementation in your development environment, but of course you are still using vendor specific functionality.

(This problem has creeped up in the past with other XML APIs as well when Sun changed the provider.  org.w3c.dom.Element used to print XML from toString, but it was provider behavior, then one day it changed and many people's code broke!)

Comment: Thanks Affe, this was the exact problem and the solution to this is to get away with toString()